# Implement configurable sort criterias

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need to be able to sort an object by multiple conditions, and these sorts need to be configurable from the application.properties file (as in it should be possible to specify in the file the sorts to apply and the order).

So in my design I created a comparator for each one of the sorts, and then an enum with a supplier such as:

```
public enum CarSort {
    ENGINE(CarEngineComparator::new), BRAND(CarBrandComparator::new);

    private final Supplier<Comparator<Car>> constructor;

    CarSort(Supplier<Comparator<Car>> constructor){
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }

    Comparator<Car> newComparator() {
        return constructor.get();
    }
}
```

With this design, I then would be able to load the sorts from a properties file:

```
myapp.cars.sorts=BRAND,ENGINE
```

And chain the sorts with something like:

```
    Stream<Comparator<Car>> comparators = sorts.stream().map(CarSort::newComparator);
    return comparators
            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
            .map(comparator -> filteredCars.sorted((comparator.reversed())))
            .orElse(filteredCars)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem I have at the moment is that one of the comparators requires two parameters, so I don't think this solution holds anymore, but I can't think of any clean alternatives at the moment.

Do you know if it would be possible to adapt my current design to fit this requirement, or have any alternative viable solution?

I'm going to add more details. Let's say the specific comparator I need to add sorts cars based for example on how far they are from the client. So it could be something like this (details are not important really, only the fact that it needs an additional parameter):

```
public class CarDistanceComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

    private Location origin;

    CarDistanceComparator(Location origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        double distanceToFirstCar = DistanceService.calculateDistance(origin, o1.getLocation());
        double distanceToSecondCar = DistanceService.calculateDistance(origin, o2.getLocation());
        return Double.compare(distanceToFirstCar, distanceToSecondCar);
    }
}
```

So then what I would like is to be able to sort by BRAND, ENGINE, DISTANCE (as specified in the config file) for multiple customers. Meaning that I would need to pass a different argument each time to the DistanceComparator.

Comment: Is using a method reference the issue here?(like `CarEngineComparator::new`)?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, it might be but I'm not seeing it, how would it look like without the method reference? I mean, where or how could I pass the parameters to the CarBrandComparator for instance?

Comment: `ENGINE(() -> new CarEngineComparator(....))`

Comment: Hmm but I don't think that would work, since those parameters are not static, they are different depending on when / where I am retrieving the comparator

Comment: Please edit your question adding more details. We cannot provide a valid answer without knowing these

Comment: I think I might need a proper factory for building the comparators. I would still have the problem with the parameters since they are specific to one comparator though...

Comment: @user7 You are right. Added edit with more details and an example. Thanks!

Comment: If `Location` is not available in your enum, then you can go for factory or something else. But I don't understand one thing. You have a config `myapp.cars.sorts=BRAND,ENGINE`. But the `CarSort` hardwires the two comparators. So, how is it configurable?

Comment: Yep sorry, I meant that is configurable in the sense that the property indicates what sorts to apply and in which order. In the example, cars would be sorted first by BRAND and then by ENGINE (I read the property, and then retrieve and apply the comparator from the enum in the specified order)